# Add to the DataStage transformer for system date in format "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"

Tags: datetime, datastage

Is there any one helping me for datetime convention in Datastage?

I need to add to the datastage transformer the system date in format "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"

I'm using Datastage 7.5 version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function DateCurrentDateTime()

Comment: I don't know but maybe the function is incorrect. Do you need the type to be a dateTime or a string will be enough?

Comment: i need to have the datetime type.

Answer (score 0):

We can convert date through Parallel or Server job using differnt process.

1. In parallel job you use Field function to split the the date and time part. i.e. 
   Field(currentTimeStamp()," ",1) : " " : Field(currentTimeStamp()," ",2) ... by default date format in datastage is %yyyy-%mm-%dd, now use substring to change the format of date like %mm/%dd/%yyyy,
   so, Field(currentTimeStamp()," ",1)[6,2] : "/" : Field(currentTimeStamp()," ",1)[9,2] : "/" : Field(currentTimeStamp()," ",1)[1,4] : " " : Field(currentTimeStamp()," ",2).
2. In server job us simple use below function:
   Oconv(Iconv(DATE(),"D-YMD[4,2,2]"),"D/MDY[2,2,4]"):" ":Oconv(TIME(),"MTS")

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below function :

Oconv(Iconv(Oconv(@DATE,"D-YMD[4,2,2]"):'-':Change(Oconv(@TIME,"MTS"), ":", ":"),D-MDY[2,2,4]),'D-MDY[2,2,4]')